# Extract all numbers and multiply

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using Google App Script..

```
var string = "Test 11x Test22x Test 33x";
var multiplier = 4;
```

What I want to do is extract all numbers from string and multiply them by the multiplier.. so the desired output should be `"Test 44x Test88x Test 132x"`

I tried

```
var pattern = /(\d+)[^0-9]*/g;
var result = pattern.exec(text);
```

but it is returning only the first set of numbers.. How do I return all numbers and then multiply them, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it all in a [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) call passing each match to a [replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters).

```js
function multiplyDigits(string, multiplier) {
  const multiply = match => match * multiplier;

  return string.replace(/\d+/g, multiply)
}

const string = "Test 11x Test22x Test 33x";
const multiplier = 4;

const result = multiplyDigits(string, multiplier);

console.log(result);
// Test 44x Test88x Test 132x
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! This worked!

Answer (score 0):

#### Extract and Multiply

```
function extractandmult() {
  let s = "Test 11 Test 22 Test 33";
  let t = s.split(' ').map(e => {
    let u = parseInt(e);
    if(!isNaN(u)) {
      return u * 4;
    } else {
      return e;
    }
  })
  Logger.log(t);
}

Execution log
4:04:23 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:04:23 PM  Info    [Test, 44.0, Test, 88.0, Test, 132.0]
4:04:24 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Changed my mind it's actually pretty easy

```
function extractandmult() {
  let s = "Test 11x Test22x Test 33x";
  let a = s.match(/\d+/g).slice();
  a.forEach(e => s = s.replace(e, e * 4));
  Logger.log(s);
}


Execution log
4:23:33 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:23:32 PM  Info    Test 44x Test88x Test 132x
4:23:33 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Thanks! But this does not work for me.. because sometimes the string is:
let s = "Test 11x Test22x Test 33x";

So, I can't split by space... and the x after the numbers need to remain there..

Comment: You didn't say that

Comment: Apologies.. Any other solution?

Comment: Take a look at the second version